# Recursive search through an integer

Tags: c, if-statement, recursion

I was having some problem when trying to do a recursive in C programming. Here is the expected output:

```
Enter a number: 1234567
Enter the digit position: 3
rDigitValue1(): 5
rDigitvalue2(): 5
```

And here is my code:

```
int rdigitValue1(int num, int k)
{
    int count = 0, output;
    if (count != k) {
        rdigitValue1(num / 10, k);
        count++;
    }
    else {
        output = (num % 10);
    }
    return output;
}
```

The parameter `num` is the number whereas the parameter `k` is the position. With these code, when I try to run the program, it just crashed without prompting any error message. Any idea?

*Modified*

```
void rdigitValue2(int num, int k, int *result)
{
    if (k != 1) {
        rdigitValue2(num / 10, k - 1, result);
        *result = num;
    }
    else {
        *result = num % 10;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `k - 1` for your recursive call, you keep testing if `k == 0` and of course it never is since you keep using the same value for `k`. You also need to store the value returned from the recursive call so that you can return it:

```
output = rdigitValue1(num / 10, k - 1);
```

Comment: But I thought k was the position parameter which should never be decrement? That's why I initialized another variable count to keep track on the loop?

Comment: @Denise, the 3rd position in num is equal to the 2nd position in num/10. You can ditch your `count` variable and just test `k != 1`.

Comment: When you have decrement `k` from 3 to 1 you will have divided num by 10 two times, so num will be `12345` and that means `num % 10` will evaluate to 5.

Comment: Hello sorry for asking another question. Let's say if I were to change to pointer for the question above, I modified my code as the modified section. However, again, the program itself just crashed. Any ideas?

Comment: @Denise That code alone shouldn't crash, but it is broken because of the line `*result = num;`, which means you always just return `num` instead of the correct value. Just delete that line to fix it.

Comment: It could crash if you are calling it wrong, you must pass in a pointer to an int that has had memory allocated. `int result; rdigitValue2( 123456, 3, &result );` should do the trick.

Comment: so did you mean I should change the else statement part in rdigitValue2 to rdigitValue2(num / 10, k - 1, &result);?

Comment: @Denise , no, just delete the line `*result = num;`.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting a stack overflow! You are never decrementing digit position and keep looping. Your current code can be simplified to:

```
int rdigitValue1(int num, int k)
{
    if (k != 0) {
        rdigitValue1(num / 10, k);
    }
}
```

Comment: So how should I fix it? Also, do you think my logic was correct?

Comment: The recursive call should have `k-1` as an argument.

Comment: Unfortunately, it still crashed as in not responding

Answer (score 0):

Expected output :

```
    rDigitvalue2(): 5
```

Current output :

```
    rDigitvalue2(): 1234567
```

The function you wrote is :

```
void rdigitValue2(int num, int k, int *result)
{
if (k != 1) {
    rdigitValue2(num / 10, k - 1, result);
    *result = num;
}
else {
    *result = num % 10;
}
}
```

The above function works well in my g++ compiler. The value for *result in the end is 1234567 for your function because your recursive call ends in the line *result = num. 
You need to remove this line and modify your function to :

```
void rdigitValue2(int num, int k, int *result)
{
if (k != 1) {
    rdigitValue2(num / 10, k - 1, result);
}
else {
    *result = num % 10;
}
}
```

Output : `rDigitvalue2(): 5`

Comment: I removed that specific line already but it still not working. Any ideas?

Comment: @Denise You can check if you are trying to dereference a NULL pointer.The pointer (int *)result might be pointing to a NULL value and dereferencing such pointer can lead to segmentation fault.